# How do you get the Host Code parameter from a Recurly failed transaction?

Tags: php, recurly

When using the Recurly API in PHP

`$transaction = Recurly_Transaction::get($uuid);`

the $transaction variable doesn't contain the HOST CODE that you can find on the transaction details page under "Parameters" at

> https://{mydomain}.recurly.com/transactions/{transactionid}

How does someone get the HOST CODE via the API?

Github issue opened: https://github.com/recurly/recurly-client-php/issues/244

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for opening the gitub issue. This isn't possible today because it's not exposed in the API, but Recurly will look into adding this.